# Do apps like WhatsApp keep an always live connection with server?

Tags: android, tcp, ios, xmpp

I'm creating an application that has to realtime be live with the server. I'm not sure whether to have an always live (or checking with server every 2mins) app because it might drain the battery. What are my alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

You are right, that would drain your battery very fast and this´d be blocked by the mobile OS as they force Apps to go to sleep after some time in background.
Google has its FCM solution to push messages over to a mobile device be it Android or iOS.

[Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/)

Apple named this 
[Apple Push Notification Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1)

Answer (score 2):

WhatsApp as most of modern apps uses Push Technology.

It means that, instead of making the device **pulling** data from the server every `x` seconds or minutes, the server **pushes** data when it's neccesary to send data to the device.

It requires that the device previously identifies itself with the server. The server recognizes it and from then, the server will be able to send a **notification** to the device when it is needed.

If the device needs a little amount of data, then it can come in the notification, or, the notification can act as **wake up call** that forces the app/device to connect to the server and **pull** the data.

Google provides a free service to make this technology work in Android / iOS devices called [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/)